# Why compare address in this implementation of min?

Tags: c

The implementation of min function [here](https://github.com/lentinj/u-boot/blob/master/tools/env/fw_env.c) is done as:

```
#define min(x, y) ({                \
    typeof(x) _min1 = (x);          \
    typeof(y) _min2 = (y);          \
    (void) (&_min1 == &_min2);      \
_min1 < _min2 ? _min1 : _min2; })
```

What is the point of the 4th line?

Why do this: `(void) (&_min1 == &_min2);`   ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It generates a warning if `x` and `y` have different types:

```
int i;
long j;
(void) (&i == &j);
```

The compiler says:

```
warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
```